# How to process 10TB of 10min video in 24hours?

Tags: hadoop

I have 10TB video data and every one 10min, how to process it ? 
Is using hadoop a good solution?

Comment: You'll need one hell of a Weissman score to do that. Have you considered using the Pied Piper architecture?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'process'? If it's transcoding, perhaps the best solution is to give it to someone who has [solved the problem already](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/). So what kind of 'processing' are you doing?

Comment: @b85411 what's Pied Piper architecture ?

Comment: @AlexTaylor I have to do it by myself .

Comment: Sorry @sunny - it doesn't exist. It was a joke from the TV show Silicon Valley.